# Rustのジェネリックで関連型が特定の型であることを保証する方法

Tags: rust

```rust
fn fib<T>(a: T, b: T, n: usize) -> T
where
    T: std::ops::Add,
    // <T as std::ops::Add>::Output == T ???
{
    match n {
        0 => a,
        1 => b,
        _ => fib(a, b, n-1) + fib(a, b, n-2)
    }
}

// (計算量については突っ込まないでください)
```

このような計算をする場合、`T`+`T`->`T`であることをコンパイラに知らせる必要がありますが、その方法はありますか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Output = T>`のように関連型の型を指定できる記法があります(コンパイルを通すために`Copy`も付加しました)．

```rust
fn fib<T>(a: T, b: T, n: usize) -> T
where
    T: std::ops::Add<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    match n {
        0 => a,
        1 => b,
        _ => fib(a, b, n-1) + fib(a, b, n-2)
    }
}
```